# Create row numbers or rankings based on conditions - Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to sort my data based on a starting time. The starting time is its own column in my data. I also have a column of data that is 15 minute increments. I need to get my row numbers or rank function to start when the 15 minute increment matches the start time. This is my desired outcome:

| Start Time | 15 Min Increment | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21:00 | 21:00 | 1 |
| 21:00 | 21:15 | 2 |
| 21:00 | 21:30 | 3 |
| 21:00 | 21:45 | 4 |
| 21:00 | 22:00 | 5 |

I feel like I need a conditional statement in here to indicate where the rows/rank should start, but I haven't been able to make this happen nor have I been able to find any articles. I know that this can be done in python as a loop, but I want to see if this is something that Snowflake can handle first. It seems like it should be fairly simple! What am I missing?

I attempted a case statement "case when 15_min_incr = start_time then 1..." and tried to incorporate this into a row function, a rank function, dense_rank, etc. No luck.

Comment: using row_number() over etc. partically worked. Not sure why the comment was removed.. It's assigning a 1 value to 21:00 and then skipping to 00:00 for 2 and so on. This works- kind of. It will assign a row_number of 1 to the time 21:00. Then it skips to 00:00 (midnight) for row 2, 00:15 as 3 and so on. So it's assigning the 1 as designed but then skipping to midnight for the next rows.

Comment: In case anyone is following this, I did find a solution! dense_rank() over (partition by location, shift_date order by CASE when start_time <= 15_min_increment THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 15_min_increment) AS rank